# SQL Select * and count of another query result of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I need help with one thing;

Table is like

```
ID, name, parent
1, ABC, -
2, DEF, 1
3, GHI, 1
```

I want to get child-items count for every row, I get from table, within one selection query

```
select *, COUNT((SELECT ID FROM ... WHERE parent = this.ID)) from ...
```

Is that possible within SQL?

The result should be like

```
1, ABC, 2
2, DEF, 0
3, GHI, 0
```

Comment: Do you need hierarchical results, or would one level of parent-child relations be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table with itself.

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.id), 0) AS childcount
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

`LEFT JOIN` is necessary to handle the case where there are no children, so you get `0` in the result (`INNER JOIN` would omit those rows).

Comment: Oops, forgot the GROUP BY. Fixed.

Comment: This selected just first row - I need all rows, even without child

Comment: @user1980807 Did you use my answer before or after I added `GROUP BY` to it?

Comment: @Barmar .. selecting all columns and grouping only by one?

Comment: All the other columns are uniquely determined by the grouping column, since it's the primary key.

Comment: Now yes. Accepting as solution. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one child level then try this

```
select *, (SELECT count(B.ID) FROM Yourtable B WHERE A.Id = B.Parent)
from Yourtable A
```

**Note :** This will not work if you want to include the grand child in count

Comment: This is horrible -- O(n^2) a sub query for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Take the counts for each parent and left join it with original table on id:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.name, IFNULL(c, 0) cnt
FROM
    your_table t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        parent, COUNT(*) c
    FROM
        your_table
    GROUP BY parent) t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent;
```